# Which is best: collection.each or for each?

Tags: groovy

Which of these two ways of transversing a list is recommended:

```
List list = [1, 2, 3]
list.each { num ->
    // Do something
}
```

or

```
List list = [1, 2, 3]
for (num in list) { 
    // Do something
}
```

?

Does any of these make any difference in performance? I think, at least in terms of readability, they are both the same.

Comment: Groovy adopts a similar philosophy to Perl: there's more than one way to do it. I try to avoid both of these if I possibly can in favor of operations that act on collections, in order to reduce the side-effects in my code.

Comment: If you want to potentially break out of the loop, then the `for(x in y)` one.  If not, the former, of course if you're creating a new list from the list, then `collect` in place of `each`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing inside of the block of code.  You might want to be taking advantage of the closure's delegate or you might have a closure you want to re-use in different contexts, which would be arguments for using `each`.  If none of that applies, the `for` loop probably makes more sense and will perform a small bit better.

Answer (score -1):

From the usage POV, the main difference between them is the way how you abnormally terminate the loop.

With `for-each` it's straight-forward:

```
for (num in list) { 
   if( someCond ) break
}
```

whereas with `each` you would have to throw an exception:

```
list.each{ 
   if( someCond ) throw new Exception( "" )
}
```

which is not so nice.

Comment: Hmmm... I wouldn't advocate throwing an exception to stop an `each` block, I'd prefer to see a recomendation to just use the correct looping construct

Comment: Definitely don't use the `Exception` approach.  That is a bad idea.

Comment: "The main difference between them is the ability to abnormally terminate the loop" - I don't agree that is the main difference.  There are fundamentally different options that apply to closures which are more significant than the option to bail out.

Comment: did I write something about "advocating"?

Comment: You are here, supplying a professional opinion on a semi-permanent public forum.  I'd consider that advocating. -- _"advocate (verb) publicly recommend or support"_

Comment: He's publicly advocating **against** it, saying that it is not nice. I don't get the amount of downvotes, IMO it's a perfectly valid comparison.